# Howto keep types in JSON output with XStream

Tags: java, json, integer, converters, xstream

I'm trying to serialize a Java object to XML and JSON with XStream. For this I'm using a custom converter that uses the HierarchicalStreamWriter. The stream writer only has a setValue() method to add data. When I add data through this method the JSON output will always be a string. How can I use the converter to output integers, boolean and dates i JSON?

So in short, data is displayed as: `{ "data": "23" }`

It should be displayed as : `{ "data": 23 }`

Here is the marshal method in the converter:

```
@Override
public void marshal(Object o, HierarchicalStreamWriter writer, MarshallingContext mc) {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> src = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>) o;
    for(HashMap<String, Object> row : src) {
        writer.startNode("row");
        Iterator<String> it = row.keySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String key = it.next();
            writer.startNode(key);
            writer.setValue(row.get(key).toString());
            writer.endNode();
        }
        writer.endNode();
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you shouldn't be using `toString()` because you're not giving the JSON anything that isn't a String so it's hardly surprising you get the result you do.

```
 Object o = row.get(key);
 if (o instanceof Integer) {
   writer.setValue((Integer)o)
 } else {
   writer.setValue(o.toString())  
 }
```

This would now support `Integer` types and anything else would be a `String`. Adding in more clauses for all the things you want to support.

Also note you can iterate over a map using the below which should be more convenient:

```
  for(Entry<String, Object) e : map.entrySet())
```

Comment: As luck would have it the writer.setValue method only accepts strings.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the technique you're using for this so I don't know but I would have to guess then that there's some way of being able to specify the expected types so that the thing that is writing them out would then be converting the Strings back to there original type. If not there may not be a way of doing this.